# Canno't access to my Google Cloud instance from SSH, SSH from panel and browser

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can't access my GCE instance since this morning.
When trying by SSH I got this:
`ssh: connect to host 23.23.01.93 port 22: Operation timed out`
From Google Cloud Engine panel SSH:
`Impossible to establish a connection with the VM on port 22`

I've already checked the ports allowed by the firewall and even disabled it but still does nothing. Also checked on the GCE interface and 22 is allowed.

When accessing from the serial port console I got this:
https://hastebin.com/helefanuso.coffeescript

lsb_release is not found which from what I read online it's pretty important for SSH.
Tried to install it from serial console but I can't seems to have access to apt-get.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say you don't "have access to apt-get," do you mean that it's installed but your user doesn't have permissions, or that `which apt-get` doesn't return a path to the executable? You might need sudo to run apt-get to install lsb_release. It's also troubling that lsb_release just...disappeared. Any ideas how that happened?

Comment: Getting `Failed to fetch` or `Could not resolve 'europe-west4-a.gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com'` when trying apt-get.
I'm accessing the machine by serial port console so I guess that's why. Also I really don't know how lsb_release disappeard.

Comment: After looking at the console trace, I don't think you have a running network. I also think you have a corrupted root volume. The program `fsck` is missing and this is a big warning sign. Mount the root volume on another instance with the same OS and repair with `fsck`.